# paramiko не авторизуется

Tags: python, paramiko

Доброй ночи господа.
Какой день бьюсь с модулем Paramiko. Не хочет авторизовываться. По факту пропускает авторизацию и начинает отправлять команды. не исключаю тот факт что проблема в оборудовании. на другой железке другого производителя авторизация работает. ( но окно приветствия выглядит по другому)

```
import time
from time import gmtime, strftime


password = "root"

def cdata_mac_ont(olt,pon,onu):
    ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh_client.connect(olt, 22, username='root', password=password,
                       look_for_keys=False,
                       allow_agent=False,
                       banner_timeout=100,
                       auth_timeout=100,
                       timeout=100)
    ssh = ssh_client.invoke_shell(term='putty')
    '''ssh.send(login + '\n')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ssh.send(password + '\n')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ssh.send('enable\n')
    time.sleep(0.5)'''
    ssh.send('config\n')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ssh.send(f"show mac-address port gpon 0/0/{pon} ont {onu}\n")
    time.sleep(5)
    buffer = ssh.recv(60000)
    with open('register1111.txt', 'wb') as output_file:  # запись в файл
        output_file.write(ssh.recv(60000))
    ssh.send('exit\n')
    ssh.close()
    return buffer

print(cdata_mac_ont('192.168.0.11', '0', '2'))
```

Ниже как это выглядит на оборудовании.
Это я руками зашел другим пользователем что было наглядно.

```
[admin@192.168.0.2:67] logon via SSH successfully
```

это уже попытался зайти скрипт. как видно он начал вводить команду config вместо логина

```
[config@unknown:67] logoff
[config@unknown:67] logon via SSH failed
```

UPD 22.08.2021
Воспользовавшись другим ssh клиентом я увидел что при коннекте запрашивается  login as: . Немного изменив код пришел уже к более менее результату.

```
def connect(ip, port, command):
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(hostname=ip, username="root", password='root',
                   port=port)

    time.sleep(1)
    ssh = client.invoke_shell()
    ssh.sendall('root\n')

    time.sleep(2)
    ssh.sendall('root\n')
    time.sleep(1)
    print(ssh.recv(9999999).decode())
    client.close()
```

Но все равно не могу попасть.( пробовал разные логины)

> root
>
> User name:root
> User password: The user name or password is invalid!
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: а что, ваша система позволяет логиниться рутом? вот дела-то... Если нет что правильно, понятно, почему отлуп. Если да, что не правильно, сделайте правильно.

Comment: не важно кем я пытаюсь логиниться. Любой пользователь не логинится по скрипту.

Answer (score 1):

выполнение команды на удалённой машине по ssh:

```
def connect(ip, port, command):
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(hostname=ip, username=user, password=password, port=port)


    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
    data = stdout.read().decode('utf-8').strip('\n')
    client.close()

connect(IP, PORT, 'lpstat -p -d | awk \'NR == 1{print $2}\'')
```

Comment: Не авторизуется ваш код. Так же как и мой)

Comment: Код "боевой", проверяйте причины вне кода

Comment: Верю что код боевоей. Мой код тоже работает на других вендорах. Проблема именно с этим. Ваш код как и мой не видит поле ввода username. Я добавил в ваш код print(data) и  вижу только `user:(127.0.0.2) connection is timed out.`. Такое происходит когда на предложение о вводе логина ничего не ввести.

Comment: Есть сдвиги. Может вы подскажите что то ( обновления в шапке)

Comment: Что за оборудование/ОС/ПО?